# How to read date and time values from excel using poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have to fetch the data from an excel file. Here is the data

Pick up date    24-Oct-15

Drop off date   01-Nov-15

Pick up time    09:20:00

Drop off time   11:05 AM

Here is the code which I am using the fetch the 'Drop off date' value from the excel.

```
    String xlfile = "C:\\Test_data.xlsx";
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(xlfile));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Cell cell = null;
    cell = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(1);
    if (cell.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
    {
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    else if (cell.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
    {
    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
```

I am getting the value as  42309.0 whereas I should be getting the value as 01-Nov-15. I tried to use cell.getDateCellValue() as well but with that option, I am getting the value as Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 IST 2015.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What's wrong with the date you got? It's November 1st 2015, exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Is there any option to get the date as shown in excel i.e. 01-Nov-15 ???

Comment: Format it using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Hmmm....Thanks, will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help !!! Below code worked for me.

```
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter(); 
df.formatCellValue(cell)
```